# Rewrite SQL to LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hi I am trying to write a SQL query to LINQ query. My SQL query is like this:

```
select BookingArrivedEnquiredTime
from BookingArriveds
where BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime='2015-02-17 00:00:00.000'
order by CAST(('01/01/2000 ' + BookingArrivedEnquiredTime) AS DATETIME)
```

How can I write this query in LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try just parsing the string as DateTime:

```
var res = from item in BookingArrivedEnquiredTime.BookingArriveds
             where item.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == DateTime.Parse("2015-02-17 00:00:00.000")
             orderby DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 " + item.ToString())
             select item;
```

Comment: i tried your query but it gives this error ----------">LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. and query is ---------->var qr = from item in db.BookingArriveds where item.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == Startdate orderby DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000 " + item.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime) select item;

Comment: Yeah, it might since this is just an example. You have not provided your data table structure, and no sample data, so I am afraid that is all I can suggest for now.

Comment: hi, in my table, I have a column BookingArrivedEnquiredTime with datatype is varchar and values are like this 07:01 AM
08:51 AM
05:45 AM
09:35 AM
10:10 AM
10:09 AM
11:03 AM
12:13 PM
11:53 AM
11:27 AM
11:24 AM